# how bind md-input to md-slider value angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, material-design

I'm developing an app with Angular 2.0/meteor, and I don't know how to bind an input to md-slider.

Here's the component html :

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <form [formGroup]="filtreForm" #f="ngForm">
    <span class="panel-title"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet">  Paramétrages 0 </i></span> 
    <md-slide-toggle>On</md-slide-toggle>
      <div *ngFor="let filtre of filtres | async">
          <div *ngFor="let filtr of filtre.arguments">   
            <span class="panel-title" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet">  {{filtr.name}} </i></span>

            <md-input-container class="example-full-width" >
                <input mdInput placeholder="{{filtr.name}}" formControlName="{{filtr.name}}" value="{{filtr.value}}">
              </md-input-container>                                                    
          <md-slider
           thumb-label
           [min]="'0'"
           [max]="'200'"
           [value]="filtr.value">        
          </md-slider>
          </div>
      </div>

    <div class="btn-group  people-pager">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-quirk" (click)="appliquerFiltre()"><i class="fa fa-tencent-weibo   Try it"></i>  Appliquer ce filtre</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here's the component ts :

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, NgZone, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

//Collection import
import { Filtres } from '../../../../both/collections/filtres.collection';
import {Filtre} from "../../../../both/models/filtre.model";

import template from './tpl.dashboard.component.html';


@Component({
  selector: 'traitement_par_lot',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template
})

export class TPLcomponent implements OnInit{

  filtres: Observable<Filtre[]>;    
  filtreForm: FormGroup;

   constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.filtreForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        spread:['',Validators.required],
        density:['',Validators.required],
        curviness:['',Validators.required],
        reseed:['',Validators.required],
    });

    this.filtres = Filtres.find({}).zone();
    console.log(this.filtres);
  }

  appliquerFiltre(){

  }

}
```

This doesn't work. for now i can get the initial value from the slider but it's doesn't change when i slide

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For update the value while slidering, you can use `change` or `input` event of `md-slider`, and get the current value from it's `event.value`.

- **change** event will be fired only after the end of you slide.
- **input** event will be fired immediately when the value of slider changes

you can choose the better one for your situation.
take a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOqIfzU12cUT3e0gzE5Z?p=preview).

Comment: thanks it's work perfect but the issue now that i have 4 sliders and 4 inputs when i change 1 slide the 4 inputs change their values can you help me with this @pengyy

Comment: @Dev you should bind each of them with a specific value.

Comment: how i can do that  I try to bind each input with a value but still the same issue @pengyy

Comment: @Dev I have update the plunker with multiple sliders, check again.